# Reading & Writing Serial Port COM3 connected using USB to serial connector

Tags: php, serial-port, 64-bit

I am using Direct IO for reading and writing data to serial port for sending sms using the modem (SIMADO GDT11 IN). Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php

Code was working fine in windows10 32 bit but now I have upgraded to 64 bit OS, Now the code is not working. Can anyone let me know what will be the issue and help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Direct I/O is only usable with 32bit operating systems.
Most of the legacy applications (16bit or 32bit) either won't run well under 64bit operating systems.

Comment: Either you can downgrade to 32 bit or create a 32 bit virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you let me know how to create 32 bit virtual machine? @Michael